# Displaying Date with Timezone Abbreviation in grid But should not affect filter field date format

Tags: grid, uicomponent, filter, magento2.4.5

I'm currently working on a Magento 2.4.5 project and I'm facing an issue with the date column in the Admin Grid. I have a column named "created_at," and I want to display dates in a custom format that includes the timezone abbreviation. Here is a snippet of my column definition in the UI component XML file:

```xml
<column name="created_at" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date">
    <settings>
        <filter>dateRange</filter>
        <dataType>date</dataType>
        <label translate="true">Purchase Date</label>
        <sorting>desc</sorting>
        <!-- Display Format with timezone abbreviation -->
        <dateFormat>MMM D, YYYY h:mm:ss A z</dateFormat>   
    </settings>
</column>
```

Despite my efforts, the displayed dates are showing as expected format, and when I try to filter dates using the calendar, it doesn't work as intended.when try to select date from filter it show invalid date and value look like ``
[image: Filter Display]

Can anyone provide guidance on how to properly configure the date format, including timezone abbreviation to display and filter as it is, in Magento 2.4.5 Admin Grid? I appreciate any insights or solutions to this issue.

Comment: This format should work M D, Y h:m:s A . But for timezone you may need to do customization

Comment: Yes that's the problem `MMM D, YYYY h:mm:ss A z` format doesn't work with filter.